# CSS- position footer at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position footer at the bottom of the page, but not sticky. I have a problem when there is not enough content to cover the screen height, then the footer is not at the bottom. I have tried to set it up in CSS like this:

```
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 8rem;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 4rem;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: $gray;
}
```

With this footer is only at the bottom of the page when there is enough content on it. But, when there is not enough content then it is above the bottom. Here is the example:
[image]

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/m6mhsyky/2/) is the fiddle.

When I add to the css file, like suggested in the answers:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Then, I have a problem with pages where there is alot of content, then the footer is at the bottom on page load, but when I start to scroll down, it goes up with the content, like shown in the image:[image]

Comment: please post the html code. And it would be best if you could create a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Bydefault body take height as per inner content. Just add following CSS for this

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 4rem;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: $gray;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<footer>Footer Container</footer>
```

Comment: That works great when there is not enough content, which was the problem, but now on the pages with alot of content, the footer is at the bottom, but when I scroll down it is not at the bottom anymore.

Comment: Can you share your code

Comment: I have added fiddle to my question, where you can see the full code

Comment: it's coming in bottom after scroll, check again

Comment: not sure, what you mean, but I have posted an image of what is happening on the page with alot of content with this code

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to display property:  Try to add this in your footer css:

```
display: block;
```

So that your footer css becomes:

```
footer {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  height: 4rem;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: $gray;
}
```

If you don't want to get rid of display: flex; then try to wrap it in any parent div and then apply the display property.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that didn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: Then try position : fixed;  try to use different combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Change position value to relative in footer css block.May be its because of absolute you are getting that problem. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That is not it.

Comment: Please try this and let me know. It worked for me. Changes to be made position : absolute, width : 100%, bottom : 0px, left : 0px